# <TR> tag not subscribing events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Given the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- HTML5 -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Fri, Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function createTableRow() {
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                var strWork = "<tr onmouseover='this.style.cursor=\"pointer\";'";
                strWork += " onmouseout='this.style.cursor=\"auto\";'";
                strWork += " onclick='ShowClick(this);'";
                strWork += " id='TestCell'><td>Test!</td></tr>";
                alert(strWork);
                tr.outerHTML = strWork;
                return tr;
            }

            function BuildTable() {
                var table = document.createElement("table");
                table.appendChild(createTableRow());
                return table;
            }

            function ShowClick(obj) {
                alert(obj.id);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='alert(BuildTable().outerHTML);'>
    &nbsp;
    </body>
</html>
```

The first "alert" dialog shows the tag as I want it to be formed, however, the "onload=alert" line returns the result "<table><tr></tr></table>".

What am I doing wrong? Why aren't these events binding to the TR tag?

Also, I'd like to add that I originally assigned the events using JavaScript i.e.:

```
tr.onclick = function() { ShowClick(this); };
```

But had the exact same result...

I really don't get it, and I can't find any discussion about the problem anywhere... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please... Learn to use `console.log()` in a modern browser.

Comment: @JaredFarrish—please learn to be tolerant of browsers in use.

Comment: @RobG - Ha ha, funny stuff. Unless you're serious, in which case, wha?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: [MDN: console.log Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log#Browser_compatibility). In other words: RobG is probably using IE<=7 for web development. "Wha?" indeed. ;-)

Comment: @PPvG - I assume, "assume", that comment was dry humor. Not that browser testing is almost entirely user-controlled, having the user being the controlling entity here. Yeah, "Wha?", simply because, no other state is "necessary" unless you're a masochist.

Comment: @JaredFarrish—when testing in a variety of browsers, it's usually easiest to target the lowest common denominator. Also best to be as cross-browser as possible, so nothing wrong with using `alert` when developing and testing code. It's also less to type. :-)

Comment: @RobG - I don't even know how to argue such a position. `console.log()` is so much more useful, but if you insist, `alert` it all.

Comment: @RobG: Or wou could use **[something like this](http://patik.com/demos/consolelog/)**: `log("something");`. How is that for less to type? ;-) BTW: `console.log` plays nice with objects and arrays, with is **awesome**. I haven't used `alert` in *years*.

Comment: I was just pointing out that it's unreasonable to criticise someone for using alert for simple debugging as there are good reasons for using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code throws a `NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR` in the JavaScript console. The [W3C spec](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html#outerhtml) has this to say:

> [`element.outerHTML`] throws a `NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR` exception if the parent of the element is the `Document` node.

The same thing happens in your code. You're setting the `tr`'s `outerHTML` **before you've appended it to another Node** (e.g. the `table`). That's why its `outerHTML` can't be changed.

The easiest solution is not to use `outerHTML`. Try your original approach:

```
function createTableRow() {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  };
  tr.onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.cursor = 'auto';
  };
  tr.onclick = function() {
    ShowClick(this);
  };
  tr.id = 'TestCell';
  tr.innerHTML = '<td>Test!</td>';
  return tr;
}
```

Note that when you `alert` (or `console.log`) the `table`'s `outerHTML`, you'll see something like this:

```
<table><tr id="TestCell"><td>Test!</td></tr></table>
```

But don't let that fool you. The event handlers don't show up, but that's because they are attached directly to the DOM node, thus bypassing the HTML. Rest assured that they work perfectly.

To see for yourself, **try this live demo: [jsbin.com/oterit/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/oterit/1/edit)**

Comment: MDN is an appropriate reference if you are specifically addressing Moziall browsers. More generally, the (draft) [W3C DOM Parsing and Serialisation specification](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html#outerhtml) is a better reference since it is for all browsers, not a specific subset.

Comment: @JaredFarrish—newer W3C **specifications** don't have a version number, just a "last updated" date because they are "living documents", not static. MDN is not even aspirational, it's a community wiki of observed behaviour in Mozilla browsers. W3C specifications are targeted at both the current and future behaviour of **all** browsers.

Comment: @JaredFarrish—the OP didn't ask for advice for a specific browser, so it should be assumed that general advice was required. Therefore it seems appropriate to quote a body that is recognised as producing general specifications and standards that browser developers are expected to follow rather than a community wiki that documents the behaviour of one particular javascript implementation. That isn't to say that MDN isn't a useful resource, only that the W3C is a more appropriate reference in this case.

Comment: @RobG - Not really worth having this disagreement. Comments deleted. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Your createTableRow function is off...

You already created "tr" as the object. And then you put `"<tr"` on the very next line. as part of `strWork` variable. You're basically repeating the task and that would break the DOM.

```
function createTableRow ( ) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.setAttribute("onmouseover" , "this.style.cursor='pointer';");
    tr.setAttribute("onmouseout" , "this.style.cursor='auto';");
    tr.setAttribute("onclick" , "showClick(this);");
    tr.setAttribute("id" , "TestCell");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test!"));
    tr.appendChild(td);

    return tr;
}
```

Comment: That's because he's using `outerHTML` which considers the element itself, and is also pretty inconsistent across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have useful information, here's more. If you want to use markup to initialise a DOM fragment, you are better off to create a parent node and insert the markup as its innerHTML, e.g.:

```
function createTableRow() {
  var tBody = document.createElement('tbody');
  var strWork = "<tr onmouseover='this.style.cursor=\"pointer\";'"
              + " onmouseout='this.style.cursor=\"auto\";'"
              + " onclick='ShowClick(this);'"
              + " id='TestCell'><td>Test!</td></tr>";
  tBody.innerHTML = strWork;
  return tBody.firstChild;
}
```

But that won't work in most versions of IE as you can't use innerHTML or outerHTML to create parts of a table, though you can use it to create an entire table.

Also, (again in IE), you must add tr elements to a tbody element, not directly to a table since a tr can't be a child of a table, it must be the child of a tbody — and people say IE isn't standards compliant, :-)

The bottom line is that you are best to use pure DOM for creating tables, not markup, per other answers.

Comment: I'll upvote, although I admit I don't under the "IE Standards" part.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the part where you actually *add* the table to the body, i.e.:

```
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Either way, `outerHTML` and creating `tr` and `td` with `document.createElement` is quite inconsistent across browsers, your best bet is to use `table.insertRow` and `row.insertCell`:

```
function createTableRow(table) {
  var tr = table.insertRow(0);
  tr.onmouseover = function () { this.style.cursor = "pointer"; }
  tr.onmouseout = function () { this.style.cursor="auto"; }
  tr.onclick = function () { ShowClick(tr); }
  tr.id = "TestCell";
  var cell = tr.insertCell(0);
  cell.innerHTML = "Test!";
}

function BuildTable() {
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  table.appendChild(createTableRow());
  document.body.appendChild(table); // here's where you add the table to the page
  return table;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVhRG/1/) exemplifying it.

Comment: Note that to be compatible with browsers in use (i.e. older versions of IE), you must add the new tr to a tbody element, and add the tbody to the table.